# Can't import liblas into OSGeo4w Python on Windows machine

Tags: python, windows-7, osgeo4w, liblas

I installed the 32-bit version of OSGeo4w with the liblas-python packages on my Windows machine. When I try to import liblas into python, I get an error that no 'liblas' module can be found, even though liblas appears in the python directory of OSGeo4w.

Comment: Is the OSGeo4W Python distribution your only Python installation? If you have multiple Python installations, e.g. OSGeo4W and the standalone from python.org, you might need to add them to your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Was a solution to this ever found?

Comment: @Kersten, let me know if you decide to convert your comment to an answer. I think it is useful information. Tks.

Comment: @AndreSilva I'm hesitant to convert it into an answer since it is a common error source but by far not the only possible one that causes OPs problem.

Comment: Can you add more details and respond to comments? How did you install liblas exactly? Also, see if this post on SO helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779060/python-how-do-i-import-liblas-module. Tks.